# Need to convert my Runnable JAR file into a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, executable-jar, jobs

I have a working Jar file. It is a Web automation where when I run the code some steps are happening over a URL. (which include pressing of few buttons also).

Now I want this to run when my machine is off. For that i need to schedule a windows job in task scheduler. Is it possible to convert my runnable jar into a batch file and then add a job in scheduler an do the steps when i am offline?

My code looks like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\x201691\\eclipse-workspace\\Mt_CacheFlush\\exefiles\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(); driver.get("abc.com"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("abc"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='textMainNav' and normalize-space()='Overview']")).click(); 
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: Click **[here to edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53949915/edit)** adding your code to it. The you can remove the comment. People will have an easier time answering your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make sense of "convert" a JAR into a batch file. There's no automatic conversion between the two.

If you only want to launch the JAR file from a batch file, you can

```
path\to\particular\jre\java -jar path\to\archive.jar
```

From there, you can create a scheduled task (Task Scheduler) that invokes the batch file for whatever criteria you have. IDK if Windows can actually turn the computer *on* in order to run a task, but if it's already running, you can certainly have the script run whether you're logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, I don't think it's possible to convert a a JAR file into a Batch file. However, if you are insistent on running the JAR file from some form of Batch, you can create an extremely small batch file that will run the JAR file for you, that looks like this:

```
:start
START C:\<path-to-jar-file>
EXIT
```

Now, you can go into the task scheduler, and create a task that starts this batch file, then closes itself. I hope this helps!

Comment: why would you need the `:start`?

Comment: @timlg07 You don't necessarily need it, I'm just very picky about that way that I code. You can take it out if you want.